# An Active Directory Domain Controller to the domain .... could not be contacted

Tags: active-directory, domain, domain-controller

I got this error:

```
Note: This information is intended for a network administrator.  If you are not your network's administrator, notify the administrator that you received this information, which has been recorded in the file C:\WINDOWS\debug\dcdiag.txt.

The following error occurred when DNS was queried for the service location (SRV) resource record used to locate an Active Directory Domain Controller (AD DC) for domain "mydomain.com":

The error was: "DNS name does not exist."
(error code 0x0000232B RCODE_NAME_ERROR)

The query was for the SRV record for _ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.mydomain.com

Common causes of this error include the following:

- The DNS SRV records required to locate a AD DC for the domain are not registered in DNS. These records are registered with a DNS server automatically when a AD DC is added to a domain. They are updated by the AD DC at set intervals. This computer is configured to use DNS servers with the following IP addresses:

192.168.1.1

- One or more of the following zones do not include delegation to its child zone:

mydomain.com
com
. (the root zone)
```

I have active directory setup on a windows 2008 server (home setup 2 computers, server mentioned above and windows 10 desktop) the host computer is connected to the domain without issue. A client computer can access the server, and all its resources, however cannot log into the domain this is the error I get. DNS resolves to the correct IP, router setup to direct traffic to that IP. Tried DMZ, just to test no change, edited hosts file to point to internal network IP rather than WAN IP no change.

Web Service, SFTP, File sharing all work remotely and locally however cannot get my local computer to connect to the domain. Researched the internet heavily, none of the solutions have worked. I have a feeling I'm missing something simple.... anyone?

Comment: OK, let's ignore all of the extraneous information about the DMZ and the router. Are the clients and the DC connected to the same physical network? Do they have ip addresses in the same subnet? Do the clients use the DC for DNS? What does the DC use for DNS?

Comment: This is setup at my house, same physical network, same IP subnet, Clients do not use the DC for DNS, DC pulls DNS from the router which is specified as google DNS services. I've attempted to specify the DC for DNS as this came up in a post I found on the internet with this issue, didn't help same error. That is when I attempted to specify within the hosts file to the local IP address. Wouldn't that take DNS being the cause out of the equation?

Comment: It's probably just making a bigger mess of it. The DC should use itself for DNS, the clients should use the DC for DNS. In the properties of the DNS server on the DC you can set up forwarders.

Comment: Removed the line from the hosts file, setup forwarding on my DNS server, pointed my client computer to use that as the DNS. Connected to the domain without issue. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Glad to help...

Answer (score 5):

The DC/DNS server should use it's own ip address for primary DNS and should use 127.0.0.1 for secondary DNS (assuming a single DC/DNS server).

The clients should use the DC/DNS server for DNS.

You can configure the DNS server properties to use the Forwarders of your choice to resolve external DNS names.